# How to force "topbar" on top of "primary-navigation" if z-index is not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

The "primary-navigation" menu stays on top of the "topbar" element. 
In functions.php the top bar is located in 'storefront_before_header', I have also tried the z-index. No results. Any ideas?